# Implementing Higher-Order Components in React - Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am building an app with react / redux for managing Collection of Electronic equipment (=donations). I have several routes that their functionality - is similiar - fetching entity (it could be volunteer, donor etc) data and show it in a table.
the volunteer route:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { requestVolunteerData } from '../actions/entitiesAction';
import { volenteerColumns as columns } from '../utils/entitiesColumns/volenteerColumns';
import '../container/App.css';
import Table from '../components/Table/Table';
import Loading from '../components/Loading/Loading';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        entities: state.requestEntitiesReducer.entities,
        isPending: state.requestEntitiesReducer.isPending,
        error: state.requestEntitiesReducer.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onRequestEntities: () => dispatch(requestVolunteerData())
    }
}

class Volenteer extends Component{
    
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.onRequestEntities();
    }   
      
    render () {
        const { entities, isPending} = this.props;
        return isPending ?
            <Loading />
             :
            (
                <div className='tc'>
                    <h1 className='f2'>רשימת מתנדבים</h1>
                    <Table data={ entities } columns={ columns } /> 
                </div>
            );  
    }   
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Volenteer);
```

and a consumer route look like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { requestConsumerData } from '../actions/entitiesAction';
import { consumerColumns as columns } from '../utils/entitiesColumns/consumerColumns';
import '../container/App.css';
import Table from '../components/Table/Table';
import Loading from '../components/Loading/Loading';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        entities: state.requestEntitiesReducer.entities,
        isPending: state.requestEntitiesReducer.isPending,
        error: state.requestEntitiesReducer.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onRequestEntities: () => dispatch(requestConsumerData())
    }
}

class Consumer extends Component{
    
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.onRequestEntities();
    }   
      
    render () {
        const { entities, isPending} = this.props;
        
        return isPending ?
            <Loading />
            :
            (
                <div className='tc'>
                    <h1 className='f2'>רשימת נזקקים</h1>
                    <Table data={ entities } columns={ columns }/>
                </div>
            );  
    }   
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Consumer);
```

As you can see, they both have the same logic and the differences are:

1. the action
2. the Entity name for the h1 tag
3. the columns object
4. the data of course

so I tried to implement an HOC which look like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../container/App.css';
import Table from '../Table/Table';
import Loading from '../Loading/Loading';

export default function WithEntity (EntityComponent, action, columns, name) {

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      isPending: state.requestEntitiesReducer.isPending,
      entities: state.requestEntitiesReducer.entities,
      error: state.requestEntitiesReducer.error
    }
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      onRequestEntities: () => dispatch(action)
    }
  }

  class extends Component {

    componentDidMount () {
      this.props.onRequestEntities();
   }

    render() {
      return (
        <EntityComponent {...this.props} />
      ) 
    }
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EntityComponent);
}
```

and the volunteer should look like:

```
const volunteerHoc = WithEntity (volunteer, action, columns, name);
const consumerHoc = WithEntity (consumer, action, columns, name)
```

but I did not understand how to inject the Loading and Table components, and wht the name of the class inside the HOC should be-
should I use another HOC - something like WithLoader that receive the data from the first one and render the Loading and Table components with the proper data? just to mention that connect is HOC itself so I need to return the EntityComponent to the redux store :

```
return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EntityComponent);
```

I Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made it, the HOC takes a basic component, Expands the functionality (by adding methods and managing state for ex) and return a new (henanced) comp with this props.
lets create a simple volunteer comp:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { requestVolunteerData } from '../actions/entitiesAction';
import { volenteerColumns as columns } from '../utils/entitiesColumns/volenteerColumns';
import '../container/App.css';
import WithEntity from '../components/HOC/WithEntity.jsx';
import Table from '../components/Table/Table';
import Loading from '../components/Loading/Loading';


class Volenteer extends Component {
    render() {
        const { entities, isPending} = this.props;
        return isPending ?
            <Loading />
             :
            (
                <div className='tc'>
                    <h1 className='f2'>רשימת מתנדבים</h1>
                    <Table data={ entities } columns={ columns } /> 
                </div>
            );  
    }
}

const VolenteerHOC = WithEntity(Volenteer, requestVolunteerData() );
export default VolenteerHOC;
```

now lets create the HOC WithEntity that managing the state and return the new cmop to redux state by connect:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const WithEntity = (EntityComponent, action) => {

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      isPending: state.requestEntitiesReducer.isPending,
      entities: state.requestEntitiesReducer.entities,
      error: state.requestEntitiesReducer.error
    }
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      onRequestEntities: () => dispatch(action)
    }
  }

  class NewCmoponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
      this.props.onRequestEntities();
    }

    render() {
      const { entities, isPending} = this.props;
      return (
        <EntityComponent {...this.props} />
      ) 
    }
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewCmoponent );
}

export default WithEntity;
```

Now same route can be simply generated via this HOC.

check out this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsBQj6X7UK8